# Clicking on a button doesn't work after navigating back to the page

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have single button on a page. Clicking on that button navigates to a desired page. Problem occurs when I go back to previous page and when I click on a button nothing happens.

I observe that it triggers a method in js controller, but not routing to a desired page.

view:

```
<fieldset  class="btn-row" ng-if="edt.response==='Edit'">
 <div class="btn-sub" ng-click="edt.responses()">Edit</div>
</fieldset>
```

controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict':
  AppModule.controller("edtCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$http", "$localStorage", "$window", "$filter", edtCtrl])

  function edtCtrl($scope, $location, $http, $localStorage, $window, $filter) {
        var vm = this;
  ...

   function init() {
     vm.response = 'Edit';
   };

  ...

  vm.responses = function() {

     console.log("routing to next page");
     Model.state='editPage';
  };

});
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough code here.  How can we diagnose a routing problem if `console.log("routing to next page");` is all you show us?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have found the issue. We have $scope.watch('Model.state',.. ) which watches for value change in state variable. When I go back to previous page the value of this state variable is not changing so no routing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this issue.

Need to reset Model.state='' ; in the editPage controller since this state variable has been watched by $scope.watch()